# How to use LINQ in C++/CLI - in VS 2010/.Net 4.0

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, c++-cli

Just wondering if there is a way to use LINQ in C++/CLI. I found one post that was focused on VS 2008 and required a bunch of workarounds for the System::String class. I have seen some framework replacements on CodeProject, but I was wondering if there is a way to use it directly in C++/CLI. If you can, anyone have a good example?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the Linq methods that are defined in the `System::Linq` namespace, but you'll have to jump through a couple extra hoops.

First, C++/CLI doesn't support extension methods. However, the extension methods are regular methods defined on various classes in `System::Linq`, so you can call them directly.

```
List<int>^ list = gcnew List<int>();
int i = Enumerable::FirstOrDefault(list);
```

Second, C++/CLI doesn't support lambda expressions. The only workaround is to declare an actual method, and pass that as a delegate.

```
ref class Foo
{
public:
    static bool GreaterThanZero(int i) { return i > 0; }

    void Bar()
    {
        List<int>^ list = gcnew List<int>();
        int i = Enumerable::FirstOrDefault(list, gcnew Func<int, bool>(&Foo::GreaterThanZero));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use C++11 lambda for `GreaterThanZero` function ?

Comment: Can it be extended for

           static bool GreaterThanX(int i, int x) { return i > x; }

Comment: This was the extra piece of information that I needed to know to make this work but excellent answer, extremely helpful.

Right-click the References node of your project > Add Reference > select System.Core

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909996/c-cli-and-using-systemlinq-not-working

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about "Language Integrated Query" or the `System::Linq` namespace?  Every programmer I know prefers the function call syntax instead of LINQ syntax.

C++/CLI does not support LINQ syntax.  Databases have supported a form of language integrated query in the past, called Embedded SQL, which is pretty much dead these days.  Embedded SQL (and later LINQ-to-SQL) was a dumb idea to begin with, people have since figured out that database query logic should be in the database and not mixed into the business logic.

LINQ-to-objects is a more useful idea, but SQL syntax just feels out of place.  So C# programmers tend to call the LINQ library functions directly.

C++ doesn't really need LINQ, because we have templates.  The standard library algorithms made possible by templates are a superset of the advantages of LINQ: They can be specialized for particular containers, but you get a good default implementation without any help from the container class.  And they compile to much more efficient code, because overload resolution happens after specialization (unlike generics).  Ok, templates aren't as good for runtime reflection as generics, but C# extension methods don't play well with runtime reflection either.  The biggest drawback of the C++ standard algorithms has been the verbosity of writing predicate functors, but C++0x introduces lambdas which take care of that.

Really what C++/CLI needs is a version of the standard algorithms that works on .NET containers.  And [here it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386172.aspx).  For example, LINQ's `Where` method corresponds pretty closely to `find_if`.  Now we just need Microsoft to hurry up and implement the final C++0x spec.

Comment: I meant the function syntax. I tend to use that more often. I only use the LINQ syntax when I end up needing to do a complicated join.

Comment: @pstrjds: Well, try out the STL/CLR algorithms.  They do most of the same things LINQ does, and use the same style as the native C++ standard library.

Comment: I probably will in the future, what I was trying to duplicate was a complex combination of LINQ functions that made extensive use of lambda functions, in the end it ended up easier to just decompose the LINQ into some for loops and conditional statements.

Comment: "Every programmer I know prefers the function call syntax instead of LINQ syntax." You are a lucky person.

Comment: 'Dumb idea', 'Every programmer' -- somewhat unhelpful statements.

Comment: @Oleg: Quoting me out of context is even less helpful.  I didn't say *every programmer*.  I said *every programmer I know*.

Comment: I HEART LINQ + LAMBDA expressions...  very cool stuff indeed!