# .NET: Get HashSet element using First() or Take()

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, hashset, visual-c++-2010

Ok, I am stuck with a .NET beginners problem. I am using C++/CLI so it is a little hard to find code examples. WWW gave me a lot of stuff to read - but no solution.

I am using .NETs HashSet. I tried to take/get a random element of the set. It must not actually be a **random** element, it also may be the first or last. Simply any one element.

There is no method providing this. However the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx lists some so called "Extension methods". One of them that would solve my problem is `First()`. Alas I have no idea how to use it. I tried `myHashSet->First()` and some other rubbish but the compiler tells me it doesn't know that method.

So, please tell me how I can call that First() "Extension Method" on a HashSet using **C++/CLI**.

Comment: sounds like you are just missing some namespace imports (`System.Linq` specifically); can you access `System.Linq.Enumerable.First<T>(...)` ?

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I tried something like this but I used the wrong namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `First` method is one of the many extension methods provided by Linq.
Given you are using C++/CLI, you might want to check [this question on how to use Linq with C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643734/how-to-use-linq-in-c-cli-in-vs-2010-net-4-0).

Comment: Very useful post. Also explains why those functions are called "Methods" with actually being methods in C++/CLI. Thanks!

Comment: *without* actually being methods