# Why C++ CLI does not let to use extension methods?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, extension-methods

My code in C++ CLI :

```
[System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ExtensionAttribute]
public ref class MyExtensions abstract sealed {
public:          
    [System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ExtensionAttribute]
    static System::String^ SetC() {
        return gcnew System::String("{") + gcnew System::String("}")  ;
    }
}
```

But following line throw an error that String has no member SetC.

```
System::String("").SetC();
```

I have also tried to use following code too :

```
gcnew System::String("")->SetC();
```

Is anything missed ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++/CLI will let you use the extension methods, but you'll have to call it as a regular static method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643734/how-to-use-linq-in-c-cli-in-vs-2010-net-4-0/5645267#5645267) for some examples, using Linq's First() as the example extension method to call.

Comment: There is just one more problem which I have posted as a new question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419974/why-c-sharp-change-my-color-structure-to-valuetype