# Why C# change my color structure to ValueType?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, extension-methods

I have defined following code in C++ CLI.
However when I want to call SetColor the first parameter which is supposed to appear as System.Drawing.Color; appears as ValueType.
This also let me to pass any variable into it. No matter if it's `Color` or not.

```
[System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ExtensionAttribute]
public ref class MyExtensions abstract sealed {
public:        
    [System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ExtensionAttribute]
    static System::String^ SetColor(System::String^ in, System::Drawing::Color^ ext) {
        return gcnew System::String("{") +
            ext->R.ToString("X") + ext->G.ToString("X") + ext->B.ToString("X")
            + gcnew System::String("}")  + in;
    }        
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Color is a struct. Remove the `^` from the parameter `System::Drawing::Color^ ext`.

Also, `gcnew System::String("{")` is redundant. Just use `"{"` directly, it's already a String object.

Comment: This did not help and my problem still is still alive!

Comment: In your edited question, you removed the `^`, but you left the calls to the R, G, and B properties as `->`. They should switch to `.`. Is what you have compiling right now?

Comment: Sorry I had to refresh the CLI project to fix this. thank you one again.