# How to pass a ref parameter from c++ to c# method?

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

i have a c++ dll (Cli) that is calling to methods in a c# dll.

the c# dll has the following method signature:

```
Class MyClass
{
   void DoSomeWork(ref ClassA a, ClassB b);
}
```

if there was **no ref** in the signature my code is something like this:

```
MyClass^ myClass = gcnew MyClass();
ClassA a = gcnew ClassA();
ClassB b = gcnew ClassB();
myClass->DoSomeWork(a, b);
```

how do i call it from the c++ code if there is a ref in the signature?

one more queastion i have -
in c# i can call the Any() method on array but for some reason doing it the c++/cli is not working

```
if (reply->Any())
```

i get an error: error C2039: 'Any' : is not a member of 'System::Array'

any help would be appricated

thx

Comment: C++/CLI does use annotation at the call site, the code you'd use is identical.  Any() is an extension method, not supported in C++/CLI.  You have to call Enumerable::Any() explicitly.  Ask only one question per post please.

Answer (score 0):

If you [compile your C++ DLL as a Managed Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235638%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) then you should be able to access it just like you do with any C# assembly.

Comment: not really, since i can't just call it myClass->DoSomeWork(ref a, b); ref is not a valid syntax in c++/cli

Answer (score 0):

1a) You could use: `myClass->DoSomeWork(*a, b);`

1b) If `ClassA` is a class then `ref` is redundant anyway.

2) regarding `if (reply->Any())` check whether you have in your source code: `using namespace System::Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need to do anything to pass `ref` parameters in C++/CLI. The method `void DoSomeWork(ref ClassA a, ClassB b);` in C# is seen as `void DoSomeWork(ClassA^% a, ClassB^ b);` in C++/CLI. Think of the `%` as equivalent to `&` in unmanaged C++: you don't need to add anything special to the method call to pass the parameter that way.
2. [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) is an extension method, defined on [`Linq::Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5645267/480937) for how to call extension methods in C++/CLI.